# Numerical Fourier Transform of bivariate functon

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a function $f(x,y)$ which was calculated on lattice/grid, so I have arrray

```
array={x,y,f[x,y]}
```

I would like to find Fourier transform of this function. Can I just use `Fourier[array]`? I have read documentation but still confuse.

Comment: You need your data in a 2d array so like this {{f[1,1], f[2,1], f[3,1],...},{f[1,2],f[2,2],f[3,2],...}...}. The documentation says _The array of data must be rectangular._ For example: you could generate the data like this: `Fourier[Table[Cos[2*x*y], {y, 0, 3, 0.2}, {x, 0, 3, 0.2}]]`